# Not redirecting to child component Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a angular-project with following structure

```
--App
  --Doctor
      --Duty Doctor
```

I need to move from doctor component to duty doctor component, while the header design of doctor component should carry over to duty doctor component also. Inorder to do that, I created the header code in doctor component and in app module , I did like the following way to move

```
 {path: 'doctor', component: DoctorComponent,
  children:[   
    {path: 'dutydoc', component: DutyDoctorComponent}
  ]
```

The page looks fine in http://localhost:4200/doctor and when redirected to http://localhost4200/doctor/dutydoc , the page doesn't loads.

In dutydoctor page, only the header component is loaded, the code which were related to duty doctor page are not loaded.I tried by printing console log in duty doctor component, but nothing printed.

Comment: You will need to share *some* code along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forgot to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your header component as well

Comment: Thanks, I have added that <router-outlet> to my component and it worked as expected !!